# Cant See Syntax Error with PHP Code

Tags: php

I'm new to php and I don't know what why I get a syntax error.

I checked over and over but I can't find where I went wrong!

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$string' (T_VARIABLE) in D:\xampp\htdocs\password\generator.php on line 12

```
   <?php 
    $lower= implode( range('a','z'));
    $upper=implode( range('A','Z'));
    $number= implode(range('0','9'));
    $symbols= '$*?!-';
    $char = $lower.$upper.$number.$symbols;

    //echo $char2;
    //echo rand(1,6);
    function random_char($string){
      $i = mt_rand (0, strlen($string)-1);
      retrun $string[$i];
    }
    echo random_char($char);

    $length=8;
    $output='';
    for($i =0; $i<$length; $i++){
      $output .= random_char($char);
    }
    echo $output;

    ?>
```

Comment: What is line 20?

Comment: replace `retrun $string[$i];` by `return $string[$i];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had simple typo on return line:

```
<?php 
    $lower= implode( range('a','z'));
    $upper=implode( range('A','Z'));
    $number= implode(range('0','9'));
    $symbols= '$*?!-';
    $char = $lower.$upper.$number.$symbols;

    //echo $char2;
    //echo rand(1,6);
    function random_char($string){
      $i = mt_rand (0, strlen($string)-1);
      return $string[$i];
    }
    echo random_char($char);

    $length=8;
    $output='';
    for($i =0; $i<$length; $i++){
      $output .= random_char($char);
    }
    echo $output;

    ?>
```